# Windows Azure Cloud Deployment "sample" folder missing

Tags: eclipse, azure, deployment, cloud

I want to deploy an Azure deployment project.
I am using eclipse version kepler, and i already installed the azure SDK and the plugin for eclipse.
The problem is, that there is no samples folder in my project after i create it.
So i can not copy the tomcat-sample-script into my startup file.  I have no idea why this is not created. I made a tutorial step by step but it did not create this folder.

Here is the tutorials i tried to do:
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Developing-a-Hello-World-Java-Application-and-Deploying-it-in-Windows-Azure1.aspx
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Developing-a-Hello-World-Java-Application-and-Deploying-it-in-Windows-Azure2.aspx

Does anybody know why the folder was not created or where i can get these sample-scripts from?
I hope you can help me!

Comment: It would help if you provided a link to the tutorial you are following, as well as indicated what version of the SDK you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
I added the tutorial to the description!

Comment: I don't know what versin my sdk is, but i downloaded it from this link:  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252838